# c++ refer to consecutive values with iterator

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

I want to calculate values of w, being the distance between two points, iteratively. In my **Aclass** i have members like **x, y** and this **w**. So I use Pitagoras Theorem, but how to do it smoothly  using iterators? This is my try, but I don't know how using iterator reference to the *"previous than pointed"* value.
Please help :)

```
Aclass temp;
for (ars::cClassC::iterator it = New_Diff.begin(); it != New_Diff.end(); it++)
            {
            temp.w = sqrt(((it->getX()-(it->getX()-1))^2+((it->getY()-(it->getY()-1)));
            New_Diff.push_back(temp);
            }
```

Comment: Careful! `x^2` is not "x to the power 2", it is "x XOR 2". So you need either to implement a `square()` function or just write x*x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the previous element:

```
ars::cClassC::iterator it_prev = New_Diff.end();
for (ars::cClassC::iterator it = New_Diff.begin(); it != New_Diff.end(); it++) {
  if (it_prev != New_Diff.end()) {
     //do the stuff here, now you have the two elements
  }
  it_prev = it;
}
```